# Error on matching the type signature on function for a list of pairs

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function that takes a list of pairs, ex. [(1,2),(1,4),(2,5),(3,4),(1,8)] and it returns the list of the sum of the second values of each pair, for each of first value in a sorted manner. ex.[14,5,4].

To do this I made a comprehension list to fold the second values from a list of pairs, and a comprehension list where the list of pairs is filtered by the first value.

```
addSec :: (Num a, Num b) => [(a,b)] -> b
addSec a = foldr (+) 0 (map snd a)

listf ::(Num a,Enum a,Eq a,Fractional a,RealFrac a)=> a ->[a]
listf g =  [ a | x <- [0..g], a <- addSec(filter ((== x ).fst) z ) ] 
                        where
                        z=[ (x,y) | x <-reverse [1..553],                                               
                                  let s = x * (fromIntegral (ceiling(504 / x))) - 504,  
                                   y <- [s..g] ]
```

I have tried the functions

```
foldr (+) 0 (map snd a) 

filter ((== x ).fst) z
```

separately on `Prelude>` and they work as intended but I get this sort of error in a program:

```
try.hs:20:36: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
    * In the expression: addSec (filter ((== x) . fst) z)
      In a stmt of a list comprehension:
        a <- addSec (filter ((== x) . fst) z)
      In the expression:
        [a | x <- [0 .. g], a <- addSec (filter ((== x) . fst) z)]
    * Relevant bindings include
        x :: a (bound at try.hs:20:18)
        z :: [(a, a)] (bound at try.hs:22:25)
        g :: a (bound at try.hs:20:7)
        listf :: a -> [a] (bound at try.hs:20:1)
   |
20 | listf g =  [ a | x <- [0..g], a <- addSec(filter ((== x ).fst) z ) ]
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I get similar errors even when the type signature is:

```
addSec :: [(a,b)] -> a
```

So I am not sure what to change. Thank you very much, I appreciate any help.

Comment: How is adding a bunch of `b`s supposed to give you an `a`?

Comment: Thank you for that, that makes sense. I am not good with type signatures. However I still get the `cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]` error, do you know what may be the cause of that?

Comment: If you have a new question, start a new post. Multiple questions in the same post generally lead to a vote to close.

Comment: Ok thank you, will do.